# Are there any gems to support single sign on through authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on

I've implemented authlogic in my app to handle user authentication. I'm also using omniauth for external authentications. However, the app will be a service that other developers will integrate with an existing website and I'd like to allow them to support single-sign-on with our app. Is there a gem already that supports single-sign on or do I just need to create my own login system?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to implement a Single Sign-On (SSO), centralized (CAS) or decentralized (OpenID). The latter "decentralized" option is the easier way, since you do not have to care about the authentication server yourself, and there are useful AuthLogic extensions for it. There is a nice Railscasts episode about [using OpenID with Authlogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic).

The centralized way is much more difficult. CAS can be realized by different protocols, either by the Central Authentication Service (CAS) protocol, for example by using the [Ruby CAS Server](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/) and the [Ruby CAS client](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-client/), or by using the SAML protocol with a suitable server (for instance the [Shibboleth server](http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/) or the [OpenAM server](http://forgerock.com/openam.html)). Both are quite difficult to implement and to understand, and there is no support in Authlogic for Shibboleth, but there seems to be an [AuthLogic plugin for CAS](https://github.com/thurisaz/authlogic_cas).